# Overwrite Javascript SetTimeout time but keep the inside function

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a tampermonkey script to reduce the time of a javascript function (SetTimeout) in order to get faster redirect of a page. The page code is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("http://linkhere.com/R4NDoM1CODEHeRE" + window.location.hash);
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

I always end up in the same page after being redirected by this one (just like those ADs that forces you to fill reCaptcha and then they transfer you back again to the same page, ask you to wait some seconds and then transfer to another reCaptcha page).

Could someone help me in this task?

Comment: `window.setTimeout = f => f()`?

Comment: Well, it didn't work, nothing happened O_o. Am I doing it wrong?

`(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.seconds = -1;
})();

window.setTimeout = f => f();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use a regex to find `http://mylinkhere.link` and immediately redirect to it (or display the button if you prefer).

Something like this should work:

```
var target = /document\.getElementById\('show'\)\.innerHTML = '<a href="([^"]*)|replace\("([^"]*)" \+ window/.exec(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
window.location = target[1] || target[2];
```

**Edit:** Corrected answer. Changed `contents` to `document.documentElement.innerHTML`.

**Edit 2:** Corrected answer again.

**Edit 3:** Updated the answer so it works on both pages from original question.

Comment: Well, it did not work as expected. Actually, nothing happened =x.
Should I just paste this below the last semi-collon of my code?

Comment: Oops! I had `contents` assigned `document.documentElement.innerHTML` in testing, but forgot to update the code. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Even with the updated asnwer, it did not "skip" the time. I tried to run it in chrome console to debug it, and chrome shows: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHH, I probably mixed things up. I wanna skip the first code, setTimeout. I just mentioned the second because of my tampermonkey script. I just wanted to show what I'm using right now in order to not conflict with it other, you know?

Comment: This means the regular expressio is failing. Instead of `/document\.getElementById\('show'\)\.innerHTML = '<a href="([^"]*)/` try something like `/= <a href="([^"]*)/`.

Comment: Please, take a look at my question again. Probably you will understand what I need now =P. I confused you by showing 2 codes.

Comment: OK, so the first regex actually did work for my first problem. Now it shows the button and automatically starts download. But this second one, as soon as I load the page, chrome console reports:

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:17:126)
    at Window.eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:19:3)
    at <anonymous>:2:297
    at window.seconds (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:2:1)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:3:3)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:26:6)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (:2:297), <anonymous>:26:50)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:297
    at Object.b [as F_c] (<anonymous>:2:142)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144016/discussion-between-originato-and-diego).

Answer (score 1):

To be more general, overwrite the `window.setTimeout` function.

```
window.setTimeout = ((original) =>
  (codeOrFunc, delay, ...args) =>
    original(codeOrFunc, 0, ...args)
)(window.setTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Originato solution in chat:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.seconds = -1;
    var target = /document\.getElementById\('show'\)\.innerHTML = '<a href="([^"]*)|replace\("([^"]*)" \+ window/.exec(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    window.location = target[1] || target[2];
})();
```